# CanExecute is called but nothing happens

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a following problem:

I have command

> CancelNewFilmCommand

with code:

```
    public override void Execute(object item)
    {
        this.ViewModel.NewItem = null;
        this.ViewModel.ShowItem = null;
        var onCanExecuteChanged = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (onCanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            onCanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        AddNewFilmWindow.CanExecute(this);
    }
```

now in the Execute of the CancelNewFilmCommand I call CanExecute of the AddNewFilmWindow command. I give reference to the CancelNewFilmCommand in initializing and setting is as private field. Problem is, that AddNewFilmWindow.CanExecute(this); do nothing. I need it to un-gray button binded to AddNewFilmWindowCommand and just can't figure out how.

Can anybody help please? I am trying to solve this whole day without success :/

Comment: You shouldn't be subclassing/implementing `ICommand` or its derivatives for every command.

Comment: Why not? :O I have class for every command. And every command implements ICommand.

Comment: You should used write a generic implementation of ICommand, and expose the functionalities via `Action`(for `Execute`) and `Func<bool>`(for `CanExecute`).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by calling AddNewFilmWindow.CanExecute(this)? Is this method does/change something? What are you expecting to get after calling this method? I think it would be better if you post this method and describe what exactly this method should does and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the  `AddNewFilmWindow.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` instead of `AddNewFilmWindow.CanExecuteChanged(this)`

Comment: Hey! I don't have RaiseCanExecuteChanged method defined and I cannot find any example of implementation. :/

Comment: Please check the below link which will help you Implementing RaiseCanExecuteChanged .........https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wpf-disciples/8aMNS1ns6ig

Comment: I dunno it seems to me that RaiseCanExecuteChanged() is thing of RelayCommands. In the google thread you pointed there is a lot of referencing to RelayCommands which I am not using.

Comment: Ok. the other way would be using the IsEnabled property of the button